# Does AdBrite Pay per CPM Only or Do You Get Money For Clicks as Well?

Tags: advertising

Does adBrite give you any money for clicks? I'm only getting a few visitors per day, but they are clicking on ads apparently. My earnings are very low.

Comment: Okay, I found the answer here: http://help.adbrite.com/index.php?action=artikel&cat=1&id=2&artlang=en

Answer (score 1):

You are paid per:

> **Ad zone views**
>
> Ad zone views refer to the amount of
>   times a particular ad zone has been
>   shown to a user.
>
> For example: If you have placed two ad
>   zones on a single page, each zone
>   showing 5 ads, then loading that page
>   will count as two ad zone views.

And per:

> **Clicks**
>
> Clicks refer to the number of times a
>   banner or text ad has been clicked on
>   your site.

To really earn money you need very high numbers, that means hundreds, thousands of users per day.

Not only adBrite, but any advertising exchange out there that pays proportionally to the traffic of the publisher.

Be aware that you don't generate clicks! In the past I thought to be smarter then the engineers working for an ads company and I've been kicked out forever (still lucky they didn't report me to authorities).

Raise up your visibility on the web, which can be a hard job indeed, but it's possible. Some advice:

1. Write good content (means interesting)
2. Advertise it (mail/forum signatures, twitter, Facebook, comments)
3. User rewards (like top 10 comments of the month, monetary incentives, etc.)
4. Affiliation (e.g. newsletter, services)

Remember to search for people who have the kind of problems you are trying to solve.

To quote [Xand0r](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/4672/xand0r) in another [answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8189/what-is-the-best-way-to-promote-a-programming-blog/8202#8202):

> Beware however! Try not to spam your
>   links around. Make sure you are
>   linking to relevant information that
>   is helpful to those who are seeking a
>   solution to a problem.